# Option and Validation in Java

Tags: java

I want to add a new option on my system where I want to add two text files, both rental.txt and customer.txt. Inside each text are ID numbers of the customer, the videotape they need and the price.

I want to place it as an option on my code. Right now I have:

1. Add Customer
2. Rent Return
3. View List
4. Search
5. Exit

I want to add this as my sixth option. Say for example I ordered a video, it would display the price and would let me confirm the price and if I am going to buy it or not.

Here is my current code:

```
  import java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import static java.lang.System.out;

    public class RentalSystem{
    static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static File file = new File("file.txt");
    static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    static int rows;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        introduction();
        System.out.print("\n\n");
        login();
        System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        introduction();
        String repeat;
        do{
            loadFile();
            System.out.print("\nWhat do you want to do?\n\n");
            System.out.print("\n                    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
            System.out.print("\n\n                    |     1. Add customer    |   2. Rent Return |\n");
            System.out.print("\n                    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
            System.out.print("\n\n                    |     3. View List       |   4. Search      |\n");
            System.out.print("\n                    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
            System.out.print("\n\n                                             |   5. Exit        |\n");
            System.out.print("\n                                              - - - - - - - - - -");
            System.out.print("\n\nChoice:");
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    writeData();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rentData();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewList();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    search();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.print("Invalid choice: ");
                    break;
            }
            System.out.print("\nDo another Task? [y/n] ");
            repeat = input.readLine();
        }while(repeat.equals("y"));

        if(repeat!="y") System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");

    }

    public static void writeData() throws Exception{
        System.out.print("\nName: ");
        String cname = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        String add = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Phone no.: ");
        String pno = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Rental amount: ");
        String ramount = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("TapeNumber: ");
        String tno = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Title: ");
        String title = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Date Borrowed: ");
        String dborrowed = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Due Date: ");
        String ddate = input.readLine();
        createLine(cname, add, pno, ramount,tno, title, dborrowed, ddate);
        rentData();
    }

    public static void createLine(String name, String address, String phone , String rental, String tapenumber, String title, String borrowed, String due) throws Exception{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        fw.write("\nName: "+name + "\nAddress: " + address +"\nPhone no.: "+ phone+"\nRentalamount: "+rental+"\nTape no.: "+ tapenumber+"\nTitle: "+ title+"\nDate borrowed: "+borrowed +"\nDue date: "+ due+":\r\n");
        fw.close();
    }

    public static void loadFile() throws Exception{
        try{
            list.clear();
            FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fStream));
            rows = 0;
            while( br.ready())
            {
                list.add(br.readLine());
                rows++;
            }
            br.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("List not yet loaded.");
        }
    }

    public static void viewList(){
        System.out.print("\n~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~");
        System.out.print(" |List of all Costumers|");
        System.out.print("~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~");
        for(int i = 0; i <rows; i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
        public static void rentData()throws Exception
    {   System.out.print("\n~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~");
        System.out.print(" |Rent Data List|");
        System.out.print("~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~");
        System.out.print("\nEnter Customer Name: ");
        String cname = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Date Borrowed: ");
        String dborrowed = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Due Date: ");
        String ddate = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Return Date: ");
        String rdate = input.readLine();
        System.out.print("Rent Amount: ");
        String ramount = input.readLine();

        System.out.print("You pay:"+ramount);


    }
    public static void search()throws Exception
    {   System.out.print("\n~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~");
        System.out.print(" |Search Costumers|");
        System.out.print("~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~");
        System.out.print("\nEnter Costumer Name: ");
        String cname = input.readLine();
        boolean found = false;

        for(int i=0; i < rows; i++){
            String temp[] = list.get(i).split(",");

            if(cname.equals(temp[0])){
            System.out.println("Search Result:\nYou are " + temp[0] + " from " + temp[1] + "."+ temp[2] + "."+ temp[3] + "."+ temp[4] + "."+ temp[5] + " is " + temp[6] + "."+ temp[7] + " is " + temp[8] + ".");
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if(!found){
            System.out.print("No results.");
        }

    }

        public static boolean evaluate(String uname, String pass){
        if (uname.equals("admin")&&pass.equals("12345")) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public static String login()throws Exception{
        BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int counter=0;
        do{
            System.out.print("Username:");
            String uname =input.readLine();
            System.out.print("Password:");
            String pass =input.readLine();

            boolean accept= evaluate(uname,pass);

            if(accept){
                break;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Incorrect username or password!");
                    counter ++;
                    }
        }while(counter<3);

            if(counter !=3) return "Login Successful";
            else return "Login Failed";
            }
        public static void introduction() throws Exception{

        System.out.println("                  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
        System.out.println("                  !                  R E N T A L                  !");
        System.out.println("                   ! ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ !  =================  ! ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ !");
        System.out.println("                  !                  S Y S T E M                  !");
        System.out.println("                  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
        }

}
```

Comment: I want to add another option called "Rent a Movie" where I will be presented the id number of the movie, the title and the price. It would ask me which of the following should I buy, and confirms the price. I added another public static void class in it...but I don't know how to get it done.

Comment: I would have been lot easier if you had used a database like mysql

Comment: so you don't know the logic for adding 2 text files or just adding a option is the problem?

Comment: adding them and making functions for them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make a enum:

```
public enum ActionEnum{
    AddCustomer(1) { 
              public void action(){
                 RentalSystem.writeData();
               }
     },
    RentReturn(2){ 
              public void action(){
                 RentalSystem.rentData();
               }
     },
    ViewList(3){ 
              public void action(){
                 RentalSystem.viewList();
               }
     },
    Search(4){ 
              public void action(){
                 RentalSystem.search();
               }
     },
    Exit(5){ 
              public void action(){
                 RentalSystem.exit();
               }
     };
     private final int index;
     private ActionEnum(int index){
         this.index = index;
     }


    public abstract void action();

    public static ActionEnum fromIndex(int ix){
            for(ActionEnum action:values()){
                            if(action.index==ix) {
                                            return action;
                            }
           }
       return null;
     }

    };
```

In your code you call instead of switch:

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

ActionEnum actionEnum = ActionEnum.fromIndex(choice);

if(actionEnum==null){

 System.out.print("Invalid choice: ");

}else{

  actionEnum.action();

}
```

Now you can extend only ActionEnum class - you modify only one place of code.
Look at "Effective Java: A Programming Language Guide" Joshua Bloch.